# How To Add Numbers To Dates

Tags: java, loops, date, if-statement

Trying to figure out how to add dates to a non-specified int using an if statement.

Trying to write a program that would be used for a library system. In which the user must input the type of item being checked out. (Either classified as NEW or OLD). The user must also the checkout date. If the item is classified as NEW then the due date is 14 days after the checkout date. Otherwise, if it's not a new item, the use has 21 days.  How would I write an if statement that allows me to add either 21 or 14 to the date of the day the user inputs? I tried using a for loop but given the exact day isn't define and the user may enter whatever day they please, I'm having difficulty getting my intended output. This is for my intro Java course, so there may be some elements that I haven't learned yet. Below is some code that I would have thought would work but given that there is no pre-defined value for coDay, I'm having trouble figuring out how it would successfully add 14 days to the inputted day.

```
String releaseType;
int coDay; 

for (int i = 0; i <= 14; i++){
         if(releaseType == "NEW"){
      }

      System.out.println(coDay);
```

If the user inputs "2" for coDay and "NEW" for releaseType, I'm expecting the coDay to be 16.

I understand that I may need to add other variables to my program. And I know that I need to add other elements to the date not then adding to the next month if there are only 30 days within that month, but I'll cross that bridge when the time comes

Comment: I understand that I may need to add other variables to my program. And I know that I need to add other elements to the date not then adding to the next month if there are only 30 days within that month, but I'll cross that bridge when the time comes.

Comment: If this is school work (homework assignment), say so up front.

Comment: @BasilBourque In all fairness the questioner says *This is for my intro Java course*. I agree that it’s a nice piece of information to have when trying to help.

Comment: As an aside don’t compare strings using `==`. It sometimes works, sometimes not. Use `.equals`, it works every time.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a java date, not something custom with ints, like `LocalDate`, and with a type you may add the good number of day :

```
static LocalDate checkoutDate(LocalDate date, String type){
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("NEW"))
        return date.plusDays(14);
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("OLD"))
        return date.plusDays(21);
    else 
        return date;
}
// without specific object but can't handle month problematic
static int checkoutDate(int day, String type){
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("NEW"))
        return day + 14;
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("OLD"))
        return day + 21;
    else 
        return day;
}
```

Then set, or ask the user a date and a type and use it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(checkoutDate(date, "NEW")); // 2019-10-20
    System.out.println(checkoutDate(date, "OLD")); // 2019-10-27
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It may be that the questioner is not supposed to use the library class `LocalDate` in his/her homework, but presenting the option, if only to other readers, is good IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You have said that you need not worry about the looping of 30 days and thus you simply desire the flat number of days.

I am assuming you have also requested a number from the user as well as the release type.

Knowing this, we may write the following:

```
String releaseType;
int coDay;

// Insert your code to scan the users input.

if (releaseType == "NEW") {
    coDay += 14;
} else {
    coDay += 21;
}

System.out.println(coDay);
```

`+=` means "equivalent to itself, plus ...". So `coDay += 14` means `coDay = coDay + 14`, meaning that we are able to add 14 days to the users input, if it is `"NEW"`, and if not, add 21 instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have maybe 7 weeks of java under my belt, so there are a lot of things I have yet to learn.

Comment: @GraysonG No worries. Please do keep in mind that my answer here is assuming you want to continue using integers for days. See @azro's answer for a more complete method that will save you in the future `when the time comes`.